# No Wifi Adapter Found. Make sure you have a wifi adapter plugged and turned on

Tags: wireless, 22.04, dell, mediatek

I installed Ubuntu 22.04.2 on a Dell Inspiron 14 7425 2-in-1 two months ago.  Wifi was working fine until this past week when I had no connection. When I went to Settings->Wi-Fi Wi-Fi was turned off and when I turned it on I received the message

> No Wifi Adapter Found.  Make sure you have a wifi adapter plugged and turned on

The first time this happened wifi came back after a couple of reboots.  But today rebooting has not solved the problem.  From the output of the lspci command when the wifi is working (see below) the wifi hardware is MT7921.

Here is the output of several commands when it is **not** working properly.  I will post the correct output of these commands after.

`lshw -C network` returns *nothing*

`rfkill list all` returns

> 0: hci0: Bluetooth
> Soft blocked: no
> Hard blocked: no

`lsmod | grep mt`:

> binfmt_misc            24576  1

> btmtk                  16384  1 btusb

> bluetooth             827392  34 btrtl,btmtk,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm

`nmcli` returns

> lo: unmanaged
> "lo"
> loopback (unknown), 00:00:00:00:00:00, sw, mtu 65536

> Use "nmcli device show" to get complete information about known devices and
> "nmcli connection show" to get an overview on active connection profiles.

> Consult nmcli(1) and nmcli-examples(7) manual pages for complete usage details.

`ifconfig` returns

> lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
> inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
> inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10
> loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
> RX packets 3181  bytes 227452 (227.4 KB)
> RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
> TX packets 3181  bytes 227452 (227.4 KB)
> TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

`dmesg | grep mt` returns nothing (no string)

`lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` returns nothing (no string)

`sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status` returns

> Status: install ok installed

This reminds me of a previous laptop I had with a wifi hardware switch on the side which I accidentally switched off once.  I know more recently that laptops sometimes have Fn-F# switches which disable to hardware but the [Dell Inspiron 14 7425](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-ca/inspiron-14-7425-2-in-1-laptop/inspiron-14-7425-2-in-1-setup-and-specifications/keyboard-shortcuts?guid=guid-f19b069e-337b-4db9-93c7-9e6ecfb29011&lang=en-us) does not seem to have such a key combination for disabling wifi.

Now, 7 hours later, I booted it again and the wifi is now working.  I will give the output of the same commands

`lshw -C network` returns

> *-network
> description: Wireless interface
> product: MT7921 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter
> vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
> physical id: 0
> bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
> logical name: wlp3s0
> logical name: /dev/fb0
> version: 00
> serial: 10:b1:df:a8:43:c5
> width: 64 bits
> clock: 33MHz
> capabilities: pciexpress msi pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless fb
> configuration: broadcast=yes depth=32 driver=mt7921e driverversion=5.19.0-35-generic firmware=____010000-20220209150915 ip=192.168.0.203 latency=0 link=yes mode=1920x1200 multicast=yes visual=truecolor wireless=IEEE 802.11 xres=1920 yres=1200
> resources: iomemory:fc0-fbf iomemory:fc0-fbf iomemory:fc0-fbf irq:93 memory:fcf0200000-fcf02fffff memory:fcf0300000-fcf0303fff memory:fcf0304000-fcf0304fff

`rfkill list all` returns

> 0: hci0: Bluetooth
> Soft blocked: no
> Hard blocked: no
> 1: phy0: Wireless LAN
> Soft blocked: no
> Hard blocked: no

`lsmod | grep mt` returns

> mt7921e                28672  0
> mt7921_common          90112  1 mt7921e
> mt76_connac_lib        65536  2 mt7921e,mt7921_common
> mt76                  102400  3 mt7921e,mt7921_common,mt76_connac_lib
> mac80211             1314816  3 mt76,mt7921_common,mt76_connac_lib
> btmtk                  16384  1 btusb
> binfmt_misc            24576  1
> bluetooth             827392  34 btrtl,btmtk,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
> cfg80211             1044480  4 mt76,mac80211,mt7921_common,mt76_connac_lib

`nmcli` returns

> wlp3s0: connected to MADERSTEVENS
> "MEDIATEK Renoir/Cezanne GPP Bridge"
> wifi (mt7921e), 10:B1:DF:A8:43:C5, hw, mtu 1500
> ip4 default, ip6 default
> inet4 192.168.0.203/24
> route4 192.168.0.0/24 metric 600
> route4 169.254.0.0/16 metric 1000
> route4 default via 192.168.0.248 metric 600
> inet6 fdfd:6a08:40d:0:d76a:e2a:1695:c234/64
> inet6 2607:f2c0:ead8:3cf7:9c01:65ee:8cbf:5584/64
> inet6 2607:f2c0:ead8:3cf7::c5c/128
> inet6 fdfd:6a08:40d::c5c/128
> inet6 fdfd:6a08:40d:0:e964:a4e3:e572:ec16/64
> inet6 2607:f2c0:ead8:3cf7:b7b:cc27:fff7:4036/64
> inet6 fe80::e159:c10e:50b3:2796/64
> route6 fe80::/64 metric 1024
> route6 fdfd:6a08:40d::/64 metric 600
> route6 2607:f2c0:ead8:3cf7::/64 metric 600
> route6 fdfd:6a08:40d::/48 via fe80::1aa6:f7ff:fec1:6e0e metric 600
> route6 fdfd:6a08:40d::c5c/128 metric 600
> route6 2607:f2c0:ead8:3cf7::c5c/128 metric 600
> route6 default via fe80::1aa6:f7ff:fec1:6e0e metric 600

> lo: unmanaged
> "lo"
> loopback (unknown), 00:00:00:00:00:00, sw, mtu 65536

> DNS configuration:
> servers: 192.168.0.248
> domains: lan
> interface: wlp3s0
> servers: fdfd:6a08:40d::1
> interface: wlp3s0

> Use "nmcli device show" to get complete information about known devices and "nmcli connection show" to get an overview on active connection profiles.

> Consult nmcli(1) and nmcli-examples(7) manual pages for complete usage details.

`ifconfig` returns

> lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
> inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
> inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10
> loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
> RX packets 247  bytes 25967 (25.9 KB)
> RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
> TX packets 247  bytes 25967 (25.9 KB)
> TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

> wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
> inet 192.168.0.203  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
> inet6 2607:f2c0:ead8:3cf7:9c01:65ee:8cbf:5584  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0
> inet6 2607:f2c0:ead8:3cf7:b7b:cc27:fff7:4036  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0
> inet6 fdfd:6a08:40d::c5c  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0
> inet6 fdfd:6a08:40d:0:d76a:e2a:1695:c234  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0
> inet6 2607:f2c0:ead8:3cf7::c5c  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0
> inet6 fe80::e159:c10e:50b3:2796  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
> inet6 fdfd:6a08:40d:0:e964:a4e3:e572:ec16  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0
> ether 10:b1:df:a8:43:c5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
> RX packets 1138  bytes 1385314 (1.3 MB)
> RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
> TX packets 741  bytes 166181 (166.1 KB)
> TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

`dmesg | grep mt` returns

> [    4.028603] mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
> [    4.056150] mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: ASIC revision: 79610010
> [    4.136518] mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: HW/SW Version: 0x8a108a10, Build Time: 20220209150832a
> [    4.396184] mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: WM Firmware Version: ____010000, Build Time: 20220209150915
> [    5.222637] mt7921e 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0

`lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` returns

> 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7921 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter [14c3:7961]
> Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device [105b:e0b7]
> Kernel driver in use: mt7921e
> Kernel modules: mt7921e

`sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status` returns

> Status: install ok installed

Comment: https://www.dell.com/community/Networking-Internet-Bluetooth/Dell-Inspiron-14z-Wi-Fi-connectivity-issues/m-p/4092669#M178208 doesn't look promising for fixing Wi-Fi issues with this specific model.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and also: `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status`

Comment: @chili555  When I booted to run these commands the wifi was working so I took the opportunity to report output of all commands in this working context.  Next time it is not working I will run your two commands again and report those.

Comment: @chili555 This morning the laptop had the networking problem again.  So I have now reported the output of all the suggested commands in both the working and non-working states.

Comment: Other than a defective device, I have no explanation as to why it appears and then disappears from `lspci` Even devices with no driver or a driver and no required firmware *still* appear on the PCI bus and are therefore disclosed in `lspci`. Is the card firmly seated in its PCI slot?

Comment: I'll open up the laptop and check; thanks for the suggestion